# Using srec_cat to merge OpenBLT bootloader with firmware for initial production flash

Tags: stm32, bootloader

Attempting to combine OpenBLT bootloader image with a firmware image to make one flash for production using srec_cat.  "warning: no execution start address record" is evident in the firmware.srec.

Flashing the bootloader and using the Microboot utility over USB with the firmware srec works perfectly fine.  Would like to have one flash binary for production purposes.

`srec_cat bootloader.srec firmware.srec -o combined.srec`

Yields a "warning: no execution start address record".  Attempting to ignore the warning and flash the combined.srec to STM32 hardware creates a non-booting flash.

`srec_info bootloader.srec` output:

> Format: Motorola S-Record
> Header: "bin/bootloader.srec"
> Execution Start Address: 080001D9
> Data:   08000000 - 0800381F

`srec_info firmware.srec` output:

> Format: Motorola S-Record
> Header: "http://srecord.sourceforge.net/"
> srec_info: fw-latest.srec: 12918: warning: no execution start address record
> Data:   08008000 - 0806CE43

Comment: Apparently there's an [srec-cat] tag. I would have edited to add that, but the queue is full.